# length of array reference parameter is desribed by another parameter in prototype

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Ok i have a weird problem. I have a screen class with variables `screenwidth` and `screenheight` and a `zbuffer` with length of `screen.screenwidth * screen.screenheight`. When i want to pass in the `zbuffer` to a function i do it like this,

```
void func(Screen& screen,double (&zbuffer)[screen.screenwidth*screen.screenheight]);
```

And it works. However in my player class in the .h file i define a function like this

```
void rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen,double (&zbuffer)[screen.screenwidth*screen.screenheight]);
```

Wih no problems. Then in the .cpp file i have this

```
void Player:: rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen,double (&zbuffer)[screen.screenwidth*screen.screenheight]){
}
```

The function parameters are copy and pasted but it still says it doesn't match any function declaration in the .h file. I tried changing the `zbuffers` length to 100 in both files and it worked just not with the original `screen.screenwidth*screen.screenheight` length.
Why does this work with other functions but not with this one. And why does it work in the .h file but not the .cpp file. And what are the rules about using function parameters as array sizes for another parameter? (turns out you can't do that by the way.)

i copy and pasted in  the other function it works in.

```
void render(Triangle& triangle,Player& camera,Screen& screen,double     (&zbuffer)[screen.screenwidth*screen.screenheight]);
```

i can't believe i didn't think of this before but i will just put `zbuffer` into the screen class

Comment: You are right. The code is not correctly formatted. This question is unreadable.

Comment: If you were to provide a complete minimal testcase we'd be able to give a more specific answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use one parameter value to define another parameter value.  You will have to pass the values individually:

```
class Screen
{
    //...
    int screenwidth;
    int screenheight;
    double *zbuffer;
    //...
};
```

```
class Player
{
public:
    //...
    void rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen, double *zbuffer, int numInBuffer);
    //...
};

...

void Player::rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen, double *zbuffer, int numInBuffer)
{
    // use zbuffer up to numInBuffer elements as needed...
}
```

```
Screen screen;
Player p;
...
p.rendervisiblehunks(screen, screen.zbuffer, screen.screenwidth * screen.screenheight);
```

Which can be simplified by removing the redundant parameters:

```
class Screen
{
    //...
    int screenwidth;
    int screenheight;
    std::vector<double> zbuffer;
    //...
};

class Player
{
public:
    void rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen);
};

...

void Player::rendervisiblehunks(Screen& screen)
{
    // use screen.zbuffer up to screen.zbuffer.size() elements as needed...
}
```

```
Screen screen;
Player p;
...
p.rendervisiblehunks(screen);
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good, but why did the thing i was trying to do work all of the other times i tried it?

Comment: @BenBeazley: it could never have worked the way you showed it.

Comment: It was, maybe somehow with includes or something it worked. Or here's another possibility. The other times it worked it wasnt in a class, it was in a seperate function

Comment: It doesn't matter how. It is not valid code to begin with. You *cannot* define one parameter in terms of another parameter, period.  That only works in template metaprogramming, which your example was not using.